# I can't bind javascript code with onload command

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

### Details of the project

- I have a folder containing html, css and js files.
- I'm writing JavaScript code from the outside.

So far, everything went smoothly. I'll add the function with the "Onload" command. But `onload` does not connect to the function. *(I wrote the function into the HTML file. It didn't work either.)*

---

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="fetchBookmarks()">
   HTML CODES....
</body>
```

---

**JavaScript:**

```
    function fetchBookmarks(){
        var bookmarks = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("bookmarks"));

        // get output id
        var bookmarksResults = document.getElementById("bookmarksResults");

        // build output
        bookmarksResults.innerHTML = "";
        for(var i = 0; i < bookmarks.length; i++){
            var name = bookmarks[i].name;
            var url = bookmarks[i].url;

            bookmarksResults.innerHTML += name; 
        }
    }
```

**Error**:

> (index):14 Uncaught ReferenceError: fetchBookmarks is not defined
>       at onload ((index):14)

---

**To access all the code:** [click](https://codepen.io/guldus/pen/Pgvyyz)

Comment: You've defined `fetchBookmarks()` inside `saveBookmarks()`, so it's local to that function and not visible from the outside.

Comment: Event handlers bound via `on*` HTML attributes are evaluated in global scope. `fetchBookmarks` is defined inside `saveBookmarks`, not global scope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wont load because fetchBookmarks is within the saveBookmark function. Move it outside of this function and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Just put the fetchBookmarks function outside the saveBookMarks i.e in the global scope. That should fix it.